# Android scene transition: Custom interpolator?

Tags: android, android-animation, transition

I have an activity launched with a scene transition with a shared element, and it works properly.

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), sharedView, "sharedView");
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class);
ActivityCompat.startActivity(getActivity(), intent, options.toBundle());
```

The element is animated smoothly from the old to the new activity. However, I'd like to change how the transition animates a bit, particularly the interpolator. It seems to be using the default smooth interpolator, but I'd like to use the new Material fast-out-slow-in interpolator, and I can't figure out how to specify that.

What should I do to override the default transition?

Comment: why are you using ActivityOptionsCompat?

Comment: So I don't have to check for API >= 21. Why?

Comment: So you dont care if for <21 no transition is done?

Comment: Correct, it's not crucial.

Comment: tried Window.*Transition() ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work:    ```TimeInterpolator interpolator = AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(this, android.R.interpolator.fast_out_slow_in);
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.getSharedElementEnterTransition().setInterpolator(interpolator);
    window.getSharedElementExitTransition().setInterpolator(interpolator);
    window.getSharedElementReenterTransition().setInterpolator(interpolator);
    window.getSharedElementReturnTransition().setInterpolator(interpolator);```

Answer (score 5):

In case you haven't figured it out yet:

Create a new `transitionSet` in your `/res/transition/`, define your transition tags with their properties and interpolators, then apply it to your activity style in `/res/values-v21/styles.xml`

#### Example for your NewActivity

- Create a `new_activity_transition.xml` inside `/res/transition/` which contains the following example transition tags and their interpolators:

  ```
  <transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <changeImageTransform
          android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
         />
      <arcMotion
          android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
      <changeBounds
          android:duration="300"
          android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
  </transitionSet>
  ```
- Then set it as the shared element enter transition in your `/res/values-v21/styles.xml`:

  ```
  <style name="NewActivity">
      <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@transition/new_activity_transition</item>
  </style>
  ```
- Don't forget to set the activity theme in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

  ```
  <activity
        android:name="{path to}.NewActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NewActivity">
  </activity>
  ```